# TFLite input/output quantization in multiple signatures

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

TFLite model conversion allows to automatically quantize or dequantize inputs or outputs of the model. You can do this by setting `inference_input_type` and `inference_output_type` appropriately like this.

```py
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_data_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8
```

However, as per TensorFlow 2.7 [TFLite models finally support multiple signatures](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/signatures#convert_a_model_with_signatures). These can be automatically retrieved from saved models, Keras models, or from concrete functions. However, this raises the question: how can you set quantization/dequantization for inputs and outputs at signature level? Moreover, how do you do that if a signature has multiple inputs or outputs?

It seems like `inference_input_type` and `inference_output_type` are rather limited to whatever single-input (maybe also single-output?) function the model exports via its call method. Any tips on how to handle quantization/dequantization for specific arguments in different signatures, even if manually, would be most welcome.

Comment: A little update. I've found that in case of multiple signatures, the signature targeted by `representative_dataset` (and I'd imagine also by `inference_input_type` and `inference_output_type`) is the first one *in alphabetical order* even when you convert from a list of concrete functions. It does depend on the names of your functions.

TF developers: this really needs a design improvement.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Lite converter can quantize the multiple signature-enabled models as well. Input/output overriding is also working for them.

```
def representative_dataset():
  # Feed data set for the "encode" signature.
  for data in encode_signature_dataset:
    yield (
      "encode", {
        "image": data.image,
        "bias": data.bias,
      }
    )

  # Feed data set for the "decode" signature.
  for data in decode_signature_dataset:
    yield (
      "decode", {
        "image": data.image,
        "hint": data.hint,
      },
    )
```

See the details at https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization#full_integer_quantization

Comment: So it's either all arguments quantized or none?

The issues about only one signature being quantized, and how which one to quantize is determined (apparently by name alphabetical order) still remain.